# How do require ALL datapoints recorded for large datasets within a stock chart?

Tags: amcharts, amstock

How do I ensure all data is recorded on a single amcharts3 stock chart when using fairly large datasets? `Amcharts.makeChart()` seems to omit values, despite setting [`syncDataTimestamps: true`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39013482/10297117).

I have two datasets that I am comparing with the `compared: true` setting, much like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34609219/10297117). Both datasets have datetimes in the form of strings. One dataset is significantly larger than the other. Initially I had suspected that one of the datasets was not being displayed, but after setting `compareGraphBullet: round`, I noticed a single bullet point,
[shown in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/102rP.png).

```
    var my_chart =  AmCharts.makeChart("my_chart_div", {
    type: "stock",
    theme: "light",

    dataDateFormat: "YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN:SS:QQQ",

    categoryAxis: {
        parseDates: true,
        minPeriod: 'fff'
    },
    categoryAxesSettings: {
        minPeriod: "fff",
        groupToPeriods: ['fff', 'ss']
    },

    syncDataTimestamps: true,

    dataSets: [
        {
            title: "my_first_data thing",
            fieldMappings: [{
                fromField: "reading",
                toField: "value"
            }],
            dataProvider: data1_provider,
            categoryField: "datetime",
            compared: true
        },
        {
            title: "my_second_data thing",
            fieldMappings: [{
                fromField: "target_value",
                toField: "value"
            }],
            dataProvider: data2_provider,
            categoryField: "datetime",
            compared: true
        }
    ],

    panels: [{
        // showCategoryAxis: false,
        title: "Data set #1",
        recalculateToPercents: "never",
        stockGraphs: [{
            id: "g1",
            valueField: "value",
            compareGraphBullet: 'round',
            comparable: true,
            compareField: "value"
        }],

        stockLegend: {
        }
    }]
});
```

Edit: And here's a [link to a codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZmemPo) that seems to exhibit much the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to your `groupToPeriods` setting combined with the synchronize timestamps functionality you're using. When you set `groupToPeriods`, you're instructing amCharts to group data into your specified periods when the overall `maxSeries` is reached (from smallest to largest period in the array). Even though there are only a few points in your dataset, the synchronize timestamp method creates dummy points in order for data comparisons to work, so the visible points happen to get grouped into a single point in your screenshot and showing nothing at all in your codepen.

Your only options are to either remove `groupToPeriods` or disable grouping entirely by setting `maxSeries` to 0, but the latter impacts performance. You can find more information on how stock chart data grouping works [here](http://www.amcharts.com/kbase/understanding-data-grouping-of-stock-chart/).